# is there union and intersect Haskell Prelude implementation?

Tags: data-structures, haskell, set

Is there in the Standard Prelude functions which implement the union and the intersection of sets ?

```
union      :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersect  :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

If no, may somebody can said if my implementation is efficient, (make good use of laziness and prelude function)

```
unionSet :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
unionSet as bs = foldl (\xs y -> if elem y xs then xs else xs ++ [y]) as bs

intersectSet :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersectSet as bs = let ns = [ a | a <- as, elem a bs] in [ b | b <- bs, elem b ns]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are [`union`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#union) and [`intersect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#intersect) functions on lists in the standard libraries, located in `Data.List` but not in the `Prelude` itself.

As far as efficiency goes, I'm going to say "no" to all of the above, both yours and the standard library's. There's really no way either can ever be efficient operations on a list with only an `Eq` constraint. That said, you may still find the implementation in `Data.List` informative--see the links above, which I've pointed directly to the relevant source.

**Edit** -- As a brief addendum for the sake of posterity, be sure to see Don's answer for what you actually *want* to use for this purpose, rather than the narrower question of "do these functions exist at all".

Answer (score 14):

The base library provides list versions, as camccann points out. If you want something a bit more efficient, consider **[Data.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Set.html)**, which provides:

```
union :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a

intersection :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
```

with complexity *O(n+m)*.

Comment: And note that an `Ord` constraint and a data structure with hidden representation like `Set` is as generic as you can really get while having any sort of sensible efficiency. Almost anything else is either going to be very inefficient or more limited in what it can store.