# set operation on  two lists of list

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I have two question ;

- How can I construct union of two lists of list **in an efficient way**?
- How can I take difference of two lists of list **in an efficient way**?

What I want ;

```
input :    first_list  =  ["stack", "foo", "bar" ]
           second_list =  ["foo", "like" ]

           first_list U second_list = ["stack", "foo", "bar", "like" ] 

           first_list - second_list = ["stack", "bar" ]
```

Comment: See if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986898/is-there-union-and-intersect-haskell-prelude-implementation

Comment: What does "in an efficient way" mean exactly?  Any solution you can come up with in haskell will be more efficient than doing it by hand on paper...

Comment: Search for "set operations" on this page: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/list.html. There's union, intersection, and a few others.

Comment: "In an efficient way"?  Don't use lists, to start with.

Comment: @JohnFisher I mean not in O(n^2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Set` ([union](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.1/doc/html/Data-Set.html#v%3aunion), [difference](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.1/doc/html/Data-Set.html#v%3adifference)), sorted lists ([union](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3aunion), [difference](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3aminus)), or unsorted lists ([union](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aunion), [difference](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3a-92--92-)).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [sequences](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html) which support efficient concatenation:
in O(log(min(n1,n2))) time.

```
(><) :: Seq a -> Seq a -> Seq a
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asks for union of sets (but says lists), and this is not a concatenation.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout: True, but I could have sworn that at the time I answered the question it only asked how to "efficiently append" 2 lists...