# Filter function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have two lists

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

the result i want to get is the common part of these two lists:  `[3,4,5,6]`
I tried to use filter function, but it always output error

```
filter (== a) b 
filter (== b) a
```

then combine them together

Comment: It'll be better if you shows us your '*tried to use filter function*'

Comment: What if the lists were `a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; b=[1, 2, 7, 4, 5]`. What should be the output? `[1, 2]`? `[4, 5]`? `[1, 2, 4, 5]`? `[[1, 2], [4, 5]]`?

Comment: @Bakuriu i want i list contains all the elements

Comment: you want some kind of intersection (seen as mathematical sets)?

Comment: @CarstenKönig, yes, thats what i want

Answer (score 6):

You need to iterate one list using `filter` and check if the elements from that list is present in the other list using the `elem` function:

```
inte :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
inte a b = filter (\x -> x `elem` a) b
```

Another way is see if there is any built-in library function present. As a first step, write the type signature for the function you want:

```
[a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Then run a [hoogle query](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[a]+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]) to see if there is any prebuilt function for that. There is an `intersect` function in `Data.List` which achieves exactly your objective.

Answer (score 4):

If you look just for common elements use [`intersect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect) from [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html)

```
a `intersect` b == [3,4,5,6]
```

A related question: [is there union and intersect Haskell Prelude implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986898/is-there-union-and-intersect-haskell-prelude-implementation)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use **intersect** function to take common elements from two list.

See how to use [intersect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect) function on lists.

Answer (score 1):

While you can directly use the `intersect` function on lists, I should recommend you use a more efficient, dedicated container instead of lists. If you really mean to express *sets*, then why don't you use [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html)?

> Prelude> import qualified Data.Set as Set
>   Prelude Set> let a = Set.fromList [1,2,3,4,5,6]; b = Set.fromList [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>   Loading package array-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package containers-0.5.5.1 ... linking ... done.
>   Prelude Set> Set.intersection a b
>   fromList [3,4,5,6]

This is *O*(*n* ⋅ log *n*) rather than *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>), much faster for large sets. Also, it expresses your intention much better if you use a dedicated set type: it makes it clear that you count out duplicates, and don't have any nontrivial ordering of the elements.

The downside is, the elements need to be `Ord` because the implementation uses the *canonical* ordering. An alternative would be [`HashSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.5.0/docs/Data-HashSet.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner

```
[x | x <- a, y <- b, x == y ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intersect a b = [x| x <- a, x `elem` b]
```

Using list `a` argument as a generator in `x <- a`. The Boolean expression `x elem b` filters each element.  If True added to `x` else discarded.

Comment: Explanation added. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0):

If your lists are built of increasing positive numbers, as they seem to be, you can have an O(n) solution instead of the quadratic `intersect` and friends:

```
ordzip :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
ordzip a b = g a b where 
  g a@(x:r) b@(y:q)  | x < y     = (x,0) : g r b 
                     | y < x     = (0,y) : g a q 
                     | otherwise = (x,y) : g r q 
  g a       []                   = [(x,0) | x <- a]
  g []      b                    = [(0,y) | y <- b]

diff xs ys = [x | (x,y)<- ordzip xs ys, x/=0 && y==0 ]  -- set difference
meet xs ys = [y | (x,y)<- ordzip xs ys, x/=0 && y/=0 ]  --     intersection
joyn xs ys = [z | (x,y)<- ordzip xs ys, let z=max x y]  --     union
```

The one you want here is `meet`:

> Prelude> meet [1,2,3,4,5,6] [3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
>   [3,4,5,6]

The above is just a toy code, to give us an idea. Normally, you would use `Maybe a` to convey the information of a *possible value*, instead of using the specially separated element, like I do with `0` above. A value of type [`Maybe a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#t:Maybe) can be either `Nothing` or `Just a`.

But actually, we would never have a `(Nothing, Nothing)` combination, as we choose either one of the two or both in `ordzip`, but never *none*, right? So what we really need here is [`Data.These.These`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.4.2/docs/Data-These.html#t:These):

```
import Data.These

ordzip :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [b] -> [These a b]
ordzip a@(x:t) b@(y:r) = case compare x y of
                            LT -> This  x   : ordzip t b 
                            GT -> That    y : ordzip a r 
                            EQ -> These x y : ordzip t r 
ordzip a       []      = map This a
ordzip []      b       = map That b

diff = catThis .: ordzip 
meet = map snd .: catThese .: ordzip
joyn = map (these id id const) .: ordzip
-- infixr 8 .: ; (f .: g) x y = f (g x y)
```

Re-writing these three set functions by merging their definitions with the `ordzip` above can lead to  more efficient code in some cases (e.g. there's no need to attach the extra tails with `ordzip a []` or `ordzip [] b` just so they are discarded in `meet`). Moreover, it would made `meet` (or `diff`) properly productive when one of its argument lists is infinite and the other is finite. The three definitions above are more of an *executable specification*.

Also sometimes we might need to decide the equality with some additional predicate, not just plain `compare`, and we might construct the elements of the result differently, as we might need them (e.g. including both `x` and `y` in the results in `meet`).

These functions work with ordered lists. There's also the [data-ordlist package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.6.1) for this with much more tools in it.