# Is it worth converting to Sets?

Tags: list, haskell, set, list-comprehension

I'm dealing with lists in my program, and I want to be able to quickly check whether two lists intersect or not. My attempt at an implementation is

```
commonEle :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
commonEle _ [] = False
commonEle [] _ = False
commonEle (x:xs) ys
    |x `elem` ys = True
    |otherwise = commonEle xs ys
```

This *works*, but I'm trying to be careful with efficiency so that things don't blow up. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986898/is-there-union-and-intersect-haskell-prelude-implementation) explains in one of the answer that it is much more efficient to use sets to quickly check intersections. My list will automatically have distinct elements, so using sets might be a good idea, but the natural way to build my data is in a list comprehension, so I'd have to use the `fromList` function to turn it into a set. How do you tell which implementation is more efficient?

For the record I'm going to have to check lots of fairly small lists (~10^5 of size <100).

Comment: I think the best way to find out is to try it (measure it) - it's just my gut but I *think* with lists < 100 you might be quicker by just using lists (maybe sorting them first?)

Comment: "For the record I'm going to have to check lots of fairly small lists (~10^5 of size <100)" - Are you going to check all of the lists against a single one, or do you need to test all of the possible pairings?

Comment: Note: you **cannot** use `Set`s and obtain a strictly equivalent function. Using `Set`s implies having an `Ord a` constraint, while your function only has `Eq a`.  If you allow `Ord a` an equivalent approach could be to sort both lists and then use something like `group` and compare then "linearly" (without using `elem` just checking the heads).  In fact I believe this problem *requires* O(n^2) if allowing only `Eq a`...

Comment: @duplode Thank you, that was a careless mistake.

Comment: I would suggest defining it as `commonEle xs ys = any (\`elem\` ys) xs`. This should be marginally faster, as well as clearer IMO.

Comment: @duplode It's a simple model for a puzzle game - there's a list of (Int,Int) points that are covered on the board (of size at most 10x10, so the list will often have <<100 elements), and a list of points that would be covered by a particular move (i.e. placing a piece in a position) - these lists would be much smaller in general. So the reason for checking the intersection is a check for whether the move is possible. So I'd be checking lots of very small lists against one.

Since they're (Int,Int) they could be ordered (I didn't know Set required that) by just ordering them lexicographically.

Comment: @Kwarrtz Thanks! I didn't know about that function

Comment: @DanielLittlewood " Since they're (Int,Int) they could be ordered (I didn't know Set required that) by just ordering them lexicographically." `Set` only requires they are *orderable* (that is what the `Ord` constraint enforces). As there is already an `Ord` instance for `(Int, Int)` (and for any other reasonbaly-sized tuples of `Ord` types as well), it will work out of the box with no further intervention.

Answer (score 2):

> Are you going to check all of the lists against a single one, or do you need to test all of the possible pairings?

> I'd be checking lots of very small lists against one.

I asked that because one concern would be having to convert too many small lists with `fromList`. As one of the lists is fixed, you can avoid most of that cost by converting just the fixed list.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.Set (Set)

-- There is probably a better name for this modified version. 
commonEle :: (Ord a) => Set a -> [a] -> Bool
commonEle xs ys = any (`S.member` xs) ys
```

If you are writing a puzzle game, you might consider keeping this part of the state of the puzzle permanently as a `Set`, so that you do not have to recreate the set on every move. (If it turns out you need to keep extra information associated to the positions, there are also the `Map` types from `Data.Map`/`Data.Map.Strict`/`Data.HashMap`).

In any case, though, do follow Carsten's advice: "the best way to find out is to try it (measure it)". Also be sure to check the promised performance characteristics for the functions you plan to use in the documentation of the relevant modules.

Answer (score 2):

You mention in the comments that your sets will all be will be pairs of coordinates `(Int,Int)` where each coordinate is in the range `[1..10]`.

In that case you should use a "bit set" so that you can use the processor's bitwise AND and OR operations for set intersection and union.

The module [Data.BitSet.Dynamic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bitset-1.4.8/docs/Data-BitSet-Dynamic.html) can be used for this purpose:

```
import qualified Data.BitSet.Dynamic as B

type Bset = B.BitSet B.FasterInteger

-- convert a list of points into a bit set
toSet :: [(Int,Int)] -> Bset
toSet points = B.fromList [ fromIntegral (r*10+c) | (r,c) <- points ]

-- do two bit sets have common elements?
commonElements :: Bset -> Bset -> Bool
commonElements a b = not $ B.null $ B.intersection a b

-- add a point to a bit set
addPoint :: Bset -> (Int,Int) -> Bset
addPoint a (r,c) = B.insert (fromIntegral $ r*10+c) a

-- convert a bit set to a list of points
toPoints :: Bset -> [(Int,Int)]
toPoints a = [ (q,r) | x <- B.toList a, let (q,r) = divMod (fromIntegral x) 10 ]

-- does a set have a point?
hasPoint :: Bset -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
hasPoint a (r,c) = B.member (fromIntegral $ r*10+c) a
```

Detecting if two sets have any common elements or if a point is in a set is very fast.